# Eager-Load all entries of a List<Ref<T>>

Tags: java, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I currently use this pattern to store lists of types that are also Objectify entities:

```
@Entity
class Test{
    private List<Ref<T>> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<T> getTees(){
        List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<>(this.data.size()); // Is the entire list loaded here?
        for (Ref<T> d : this.data) {
            tmp.add(d.get()); // or every single entry here??
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

The question is: will the first time the `data`-field is used load the entire list (the data that `Ref` "points" to) from the data-storage, or will the `Ref<T>.get()`-method load each entry individually?

If so, how can a bulk-load the entire list at once?

**Note**: I don't always need the list, that's why it doesn't have the `@Load`-annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objectify will not load anything referenced unless you `.get()` it explicitly, this results in individual fetches, or you tell it to auto load all the things via `@Load`. That speeds up loading overall because it can batch process the request instead of forming several individual ones.

If by "I don't always need the list" you mean that you have distinct cases of "need" vs "not need", take a look at load groups, essentially a way to turn the `@Load` annotation on or off.

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Relationships has examples like yours
https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BasicOperations#Load_Groups to turn on/off auto loading

---

There is btw a way to load a list of `Ref`s in a single batch using
[`Map<Key<T>,T> Loader#refs(Iterable<Ref<T>> refs)`](http://docs.objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/git/apidocs/com/googlecode/objectify/cmd/Loader.html#refs%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

```
public List<T> getTees(){
    Collection<T> values = ofy().load().refs(data).values();
    return new ArrayList<T>(values);
}
```

Comment: Will calling `refs()` also load all the backing data into the `List<Ref<T>>`? Meaning when I call `get()` on any `Ref<T>` from that list, will it perform a datastore operation or have the value immediately?

Comment: Never mind, I guess the docs answer that: "**returns** as an alternative to accessing the Refs directly, a Map of the asynchronous result."

Comment: @LukasKnuth Once you've loaded an entity somehow, every consequent load should come from the [session cache](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Caching#Session_Cache). The `Map` approach allows you to request a bunch of entities asynchronous, accessing a value in the map is when it blocks until that particular value is loaded. The call to `Map#values()` requires that all are loaded. They should be available from now on regardless of how you try to get them.

Comment: Quick follow-up: The linked doc talks about the `@Cache`-Annotation. As I understand it, putting that annotation on everything that is often read will increase performance and have no penalty. I know there is no limit to the overall Memcache size (just the size of stored objects), so can I just slap that annotation on everything or is there something I'm missing (aside from the fact that it won't increase write speed)?

Comment: @LukasKnuth Correct, putting it all over the place is typically better than not using it at all because things may get faster and more importantly saves you datastore fetches that cost $$$. It makes no sense to cache entities when every access modifies them though. Memcache (the unpaid one) has not limit but it also has no guarantees, e.g. the cache could be emptied at any time or your share of it could become very small. So you should monitor how memcache behaves for you and maybe cache just the most important entities to prevent that less important ones drive the important ones out

Comment: Well you would save the initial read from datastore for entities that you modify with each access